# How to build typescript with JS execution?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, compilation

i have function that is putting all the typescript syntax together that i would be displaying in the UI using pre , is there way to put this code to compile before i add to front end ? i couldn't find any source on google.

All of the typescript code is assign to `str` that should compile.

main.js

```
    function buildTypescript(data) {
        var str = "import {Api as DK} from '@SDK/wrapper-sdk';

        import {
            IErrorDetailsHeader,
            IHeader
        } from '@cSDK/combinator-interfaces/dist/common/Header.Model';

        import {
            IDrug,
            IError,
IGetRefillsParam
        } from '@SDK/interface/Drug.Model';

       SDK.setConfig({
            env: null
        });

        let param: IGetRefillsParam = {
            "apiKey": "73a4ef3",
            "tokenId": "b87ab2",
            "startDate": "",
            "endDate": ""
        };

       SDK.Drug.getDrugs(param, (result: {
            header: IHeader
            details: IResponse
        }) => {
            console.log(result);
        });
        "
```

Compile here

```
    i want to compile `str` here to make sure typescript is valid before display on UI 

    $('#request_method_TS').text(str);
}
```

main.html

```
<div class="tab-content">
<pre id="request_method_TS" style="margin: 5px;"></pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

you need typescript compiler(transpiler) to do that and it does not exists on your client device.

you might be able to achieve that by providing api on your server (sending str to server, compile it and sending result back) but i'm not sure if it's an easy task to accomplish, mainly because references path.

if you just have simple class or models maybe (or even fixed references) it could be done, but beyond that (for example referencing other libraries) might be so time consuming to get it right.